# How to type object children based on parent's key in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A very simplified version of what I'm wanting to achieve, let's say I have a configuration object, each key is a version of config, which has child keys (all same keys) but can contain different typed values.

```js
const config = {
    version1: {
        options: ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    version2: {
        options: ["B", "D", "E"]
    },
    // and so on ...
}
```

I have set up my versions:

`type VersionNames = "version1" | "version2"`

I have my options:

```js
type Version1Options = "A" | "B" | "C"
type Version2Options = "B" | "D" | "E"
```

and then my generic:

```js
type Configuration = {
    [k in VersionNames]: {
        options: Version1Options[] | Version2Options[]
    }
}
```

This gives me an object type with two keys as expected, but the `options` key can always be any of the Options since it is a union. I want it to always be typed so that the options key under `version1` parent is typed as `Version1Options[]` only, and so on.

I know I can something like

```js
options: k extends "version1" ? Version1Options[] : Version2Options[]
```

Or I can more explicitly type every parent/child key but I also want to avoid these since I might want to add an infinite number of "versions" down the track and don't want to type it every time.

Each "version" object also follows its own interface (in reality I have deeply nested objects, this is just simplified)

Is it possible to do as generically as possible?

Answer (score 3):

Just create one `VersionOptions` type, and then use that inside your mapped `Configuration` type:

```
type VersionOptions = {
  version1: "A" | "B" | "C";
  version2: "B" | "D" | "E";
};

type Configuration = {
    [K in keyof VersionOptions]: {
        options: VersionOptions[K][]
    }
};

const config: Configuration = {
    version1: {
        options: ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    version2: {
        options: ["B", "D", "E"]
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAahBOBnAlgewHYHkzDexUAvFAN4BQUUAbgihgIwBcUARAIItQA+rAQpzxYBhFgG4K1WngBMzFv26sAIgNYBRMWQC+4sqEhQhGAGbIA5gFd4AQ1wYipCZQDaAaSjJ0UANYQQqY1gpDGw7fABdZnJKGJjUHDxEZjgkPFDEt3DncKcoLW0yMgBjDERgKBL0UzNmIyrzK1s8B2iYmlSGKNzY+LCkqGd2FgAaPhHWERzYrWHc9rp0WUdYnoTS5kH+UZYVbY0pmPytIA)</sup>

The `Configuration` type will then be resolved as:

```
type Configuration = {
    version1: {
        options: ("A" | "B" | "C")[];
    };
    version2: {
        options: ("B" | "D" | "E")[];
    };
}
```

If you still need a `VersionNames` type to refer to elsewhere, you can just define that as follows:

```
type VersionNames = keyof VersionOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some bits of what I learned in a similar situation, which @RobbyConelissen's answer helped me on.

TL;DR:

```
<PrettyPrint
  data={{
    date: '12/12/24', // string
    amountInCents: 123, // number
    isMatched: false, // boolean
  }}
  printOptions={{
    amountInCents: {
      format: (value) => {
               ^^^^^ Needs to be a `number`, but was `number | string | boolean`
        return formatCurrency(value)
      }
    }
  }}
```

I had something like this:

````
const PrettyPrinter = <
  TData extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>,
  TKey extends keyof TData,
  TPrintConfig extends Record<
    TKey,
    PrintOptions<TData, TKey>
  >
>(
  data: TData,
  printConfig: TPrintConfig
) => {}
```.

Inside my implementation, when calling `<div>{format(value)}</div>`, I was getting the error `TS2322 is assignable to the constraint of type 'TData[TKey]', but 'TData[TKey]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'`

The solution was to avoid using `Record`, don't use `TKey extends keyof TData`, something like:

```tsx
const PrettyPrinter = <
  TData extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>,
  TPrintConfig extends {
    [TKey in keyof TData]: PrintOptions<TData, TKey>
  } 
>(
  data: TData,
  printConfig: TPrintConfig
) => {}
````

I know this isn't a proper answer, I originally just wanted to comment on @RobbyConelissen's answer, but I can't really fit this into an intelligible comment

Comment: My original google search was "typescript config generics get parents key"